# How to index different types of files(pdf, word,html..etc) using SolrJ Java application

Tags: java, solrj

I am new to SolrJ. I have a requirement to index zip, pdf and html documents using the SolrJ Java API. Can anyone please give me some examples to index different types of documents, using SolrJ in java applications?

**Is there any good links that i can go through where I can find good examples in Java to index different types of documents available in a folder...**

Thank you for your help..

According to the output its clear that solrj is not indexing the .xml file that i am trying to can anyone pls comment what i am doing wrong...

**Code:**

```
 String urlString = "http://localhost:8983/solr/tests";
    HttpSolrClient solr = new HttpSolrClient.Builder(urlString).build();

    solr.setParser(new XMLResponseParser());

    File file = new File("D:/work/devtools/Solr/solr-7.6.0/example/exampledocs/hd.xml");
    InputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
    /* Tika specific */
    ContentHandler contenthandler = new BodyContentHandler(10 * 1024 * 1024);
    Metadata metadata = new Metadata();
    metadata.set(Metadata.RESOURCE_NAME_KEY, "hd.xml");
    ParseContext parseContext = new ParseContext();
    // Automatically detect best parser base on detected document type
    AutoDetectParser autodetectParser = new AutoDetectParser();
    // OOXMLParser parser = new OOXMLParser();
    autodetectParser.parse(fis, contenthandler, metadata, parseContext);
    SolrInputDocument doc = new SolrInputDocument();
    doc.addField("id", file.getCanonicalPath());
    SolrQuery query = new SolrQuery("*.*");
    // query.set("q", "price:599.99");
    QueryResponse response = solr.query(query);
```

**Output :**

```
solr query{responseHeader={status=0,QTime=0,params={q=*.*,wt=xml,version=2.2}},response={numFound=0,start=0,docs=[]}}
```

Comment: https://lucidworks.com/2012/02/14/indexing-with-solrj/

Comment: I am doing in this way to index .xml fil using solrj in java application
but it dosent work for me as i didnt see the output for hd.xml file which means it is not able to index the file in java application
could you please help me with this what i am doing wrong

Comment: Code:
core is -->tests
String urlString = "http://localhost:8983/solr/tests";
HttpSolrClient solr = new HttpSolrClient.Builder(urlString).build();
solr.setParser(new XMLResponseParser());
File file = new File("D:/work/devtools/Solr/solr-7.6.0/example/exampledocs/hd.xml");
InputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);

Comment: /* Tika specific */
ContentHandler contenthandler = new BodyContentHandler(10 * 1024 * 1024);
Metadata metadata = new Metadata();
metadata.set(Metadata.RESOURCE_NAME_KEY, "hd.xml");
ParseContext parseContext = new ParseContext();
// Automatically detect best parser base on detected document type
AutoDetectParser autodetectParser = new AutoDetectParser();
// OOXMLParser parser = new OOXMLParser();
autodetectParser.parse(fis, contenthandler, metadata, parseContext);

Comment: SolrInputDocument doc = new SolrInputDocument();
doc.addField("id", file.getCanonicalPath());
SolrQuery query = new SolrQuery("*.*");
QueryResponse response = solr.query(query);

Comment: output: solr query{responseHeader={status=0,QTime=0,params={q=*.*,wt=xml,version=2.2}},response={numFound=0,start=0,docs=[]}}

Answer (score 1):

links for basic information:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rxoS1p1TaFY&t=198s
2) https://lucene.apache.org/solr/  link to download the latest version
       How to use solrj in Java Application:
        **java version should be 1.8**
        @)download solr latest version unzip 
        1)add the dependencies in your pom.xml file
        
            org.apache.solr
            solr-solrj
            7.6.0

** start the solr from solr /bin folder and check the solr admin console by hitting this http://localhost:8983/solr/#
        2)
        basic example code:(this code is good enough to understand the solrj)

```
    create the indexfiles core in solr and use the following code 

        String urlString = "http://localhost:8983/solr/indexfiles";
            HttpSolrClient solr = new HttpSolrClient.Builder(urlString).build();

            solr.setParser(new XMLResponseParser());
            File file = new File("D:/work/devtools/Solr/solr-7.6.0/example/exampledocs/176444.zip");

            ContentStreamUpdateRequest req = new ContentStreamUpdateRequest("/update/extract");

    //        req.addFile(file, "application/pdf");//change the content type for different input files
            req.addFile(file, "text/plain");
            String fileName = file.getName();
            req.setParam("literal.id", fileName);
            req.setAction(req.getAction().COMMIT, true, true);
            NamedList<Object> result = solr.request(req);
            int status = (Integer) ((org.apache.solr.common.util.SimpleOrderedMap) (result.get("responseHeader"))).get("status");

            System.out.println("Result: " +result);
            System.out.println("solr query"+ solr.query(new SolrQuery("*.*")));



    3)query from the solr admin console using this http://localhost:8983/solr/indexfiles/select?q=SOLR1000

    just change the text(q="<text to search>") that u want to search that available in the files that u indexed

    u can find query parameter q in the solr admin console where we can give the required text to search if u are not comfortable with solr querys by default it is  *:*


NOTE:dont need to think about Apache Tika and all to integrate it with Apache solr to index zip files and all because its by default available in solr new version

****Note: dont confuse by looking into the outputs from standalone admin(which gives complete data in the output ex: hd.xml is indexed which is available in the /exampledocs folder in solr) and the output u get by indexing the same files using solrj through java application

ex:solrj it will just index the file which means from the solr admin console u can see the following as out put when u fire query
(http://localhost:8983/solr/indexfiles/select?q=*:*)
output:

{
        "id":"hd.xml",
        "stream_size":["null"],
        "x_parsed_by":["org.apache.tika.parser.DefaultParser",
          "org.apache.tika.parser.xml.DcXMLParser"],
        "stream_content_type":["text/xml"],
        "content_type":["application/xml"],
        "_version_":1624155471570010112},


But if we index throw command prompt using ---> java -Dc=name -jar post.jar *.xml the output contains the data available inside the xml file (http://localhost:8983/solr/indexfiles/select?q=*:*)
```

Comment: Thank you for the example. So what do we do with this code? Where it needs to be put and how to run this?

Answer (score 0):

Xml Specific version of code to index xml file into Solr. But Xml should in below format.

```
<add>
<doc>
 <field name="id">PMID</field>
 <field name="year_i">Year</field>
 <field name="name">ArticleTitle</field>
 <field name="abstract_s">AbstractText</field>
 <field name="cat">MeshHeading1</field>
 <field name="cat">MeshHeading2</field>
</doc>
</add>
```

Below is the code to index xml data to Solr.

```
    File xmlFile = new File("example.xml");
    Reader fileReader = new FileReader(xmlFile);
    BufferedReader bufReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    String line = bufReader.readLine();
    while( line != null){
        sb.append(line).append("\n");
        line = bufReader.readLine();
    }
    String xml2String = sb.toString();
    String urlString = String.format("http://localhost:8983/solr/%s", "pubmed1");
    HttpSolrClient server = new HttpSolrClient.Builder(urlString).build();
    server.setParser(new XMLResponseParser());
    DirectXmlRequest xmlreq = new DirectXmlRequest( "/update", xml2String );
    server.request( xmlreq );
    server.commit();
```

Talking about Apache Tika it will help you out to extract the file content. The file can be xlsx,pdf,html,xml. In case of xml file format you need to write parser to convert xml format in solr xml format. You can use XSLT in case of xml.
refer in case of Apache Tika:-
[enter link description here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/tika/tika_content_extraction.htm)